# JTabbedpane wont refresh

Tags: jtabbedpane

So, I have 3 tabs.

When i press any of the buttons in PizzaPanel.java, it is not updating the the CheckoutPanel.java file. I want the subtotal to update on the checkoutpanel to keep the running total after each button press.

I have tried repaint() and revalidate() to no avail, where am i going wrong?

---

```
            import javax.swing.*;

            public class pizzaMain
            {
                // sets up the frame and panels
                public static void main (String[] args)
                {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Pizza Dudes Pizza Palace");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
                    tp.addTab ("Welcome", new WelcomePanel());  // DONE
                    tp.addTab ("Pizza", new PizzaPanel());      //made, needs listeners
                    //tp.addTab ("Sides", new SidesPanel());        //made, needs listeners
                    //tp.addTab ("Drinks", new DrinksPanel());  //made, needs listeners
                    //tp.addTab ("Deserts", new DesertsPanel());
                    //tp.addTab("Tools", new ToolsPanel());     
                    tp.addTab ("Checkout", new CheckoutPanel());

                    frame.getContentPane().add(tp);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
```

---

import java.awt.*;
                import javax.swing.*;

```
            public class WelcomePanel extends JPanel
            {
                JLabel l1, l2;
                public WelcomePanel()
                {
                    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                    setBackground(Color.blue);

                    l1 = new JLabel("This is a interactive POS Prototype");
                    l2 = new JLabel("           SCPC CORP.              ");

                    add(l1);
                    add(l2);
                }
            }
```

---

```
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import javax.swing.*;

            public class PizzaPanel extends JPanel
            {
                CheckoutPanel cp = new CheckoutPanel();

                private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;

                public PizzaPanel()
                {
                    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

                    setBackground(Color.blue);

                    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(); 

                    b1 = new JButton("12' Cheese");
                    b1.addActionListener(listener);

                    b2 = new JButton("14' Cheese");
                    b2.addActionListener(listener);

                    b3 = new JButton("12' Meat Lover");
                    b3.addActionListener(listener);

                    b4 = new JButton("14' Meat Lover");
                    b4.addActionListener(listener);

                    b5 = new JButton("12' Supreme");
                    b5.addActionListener(listener);

                    b6 = new JButton("14' Supreme");
                    b6.addActionListener(listener);

                    add(b1);
                    add(b2);
                    add(b3);
                    add(b4);
                    add(b5);
                    add(b6);
                }

                private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        if(event.getSource() == b1) // cheese 12
                        {
                            cp.setSubtotal(9.99);       //works - sends the amnt over to the CheckoutPanel
                            cp.updateLabels();          //doesnt work
                            revalidate();               //doesnt work
                            repaint();              //doesnt work
                        }
                        else if(event.getSource() == b2) //cheese 14
                        {
                            //Set a qnty option later
                            cp.setSubtotal(12.99);
                            cp.updateLabels();
                            revalidate();               //doesnt work
                            repaint();              //doesnt work
                        }
                        else if(event.getSource() == b3) // meat 12
                        {
                            //Set a qnty option later
                            cp.setSubtotal(11.99);
                            cp.updateLabels();
                            revalidate();               //doesnt work
                            repaint();              //doesnt work
                        }
                        else if(event.getSource() == b4) // meat 14
                        {
                            //Set a qnty option later
                            cp.setSubtotal(15.99);
                            cp.updateLabels();  
                            revalidate();               //doesnt work
                            repaint();              //doesnt work
                        }
                        else if(event.getSource() == b5) //supreme 12
                        {
                            //Set a qnty option later
                            cp.setSubtotal(11.99);
                            cp.updateLabels();
                            revalidate();               //doesnt work
                            repaint();              //doesnt work
                        }
                        else if(event.getSource() == b6)//supreme 14
                        {
                            //Set a qnty option later
                            cp.setSubtotal(14.99);
                            cp.updateLabels();
                            revalidate();               //doesnt work
                            repaint();              //doesnt work
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

//getQnty
                //setQnty           needed

```
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import javax.swing.*;
            import java.text.DecimalFormat;
            import java.util.Scanner;


            public class CheckoutPanel extends JPanel 
            {
                DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

                double Tax = 0.10;      //10% tax rate
                double Subtotal;
                double Total = (Tax * Subtotal);
                JLabel l1, l2, l3;
                //double Discount;

                public CheckoutPanel()
                {


                    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                    setBackground(Color.red);

                    l1 = new JLabel("Subtotal: $" + formatter.format(Subtotal) + " ");
                    l2 = new JLabel("Tax: $" + formatter.format(Tax) + " ");
                    l3 = new JLabel("Order Total: $" + formatter.format(Total) + " ");

                    add(l1);
                    add(l2);
                    add(l3);
                }

                public void updateLabels()
                {
                    l1.setText("Subtotal: $" + formatter.format(Subtotal) + " ");
                    l2.setText("Tax: $" + formatter.format(Tax) + " ");
                    l3.setText("Order Total: $" + formatter.format(Total) + " ");
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
                public void setTax(double taxRate)
                {
                    Tax = taxRate;
                }

                public double getTax()
                {
                    return Tax;
                }

                public void setTotal(double Amount)
                {

                    Total += Amount;
                }

                public double getTotal()
                {
                    return Total;
                }

                public void setSubtotal(double Amount)
                {
                    Subtotal += Amount;
                    l1.setText("Subtotal: $" + formatter.format(Subtotal) + " ");
                    l2.setText("Tax: $" + formatter.format(Tax) + " ");
                    l3.setText("Order Total: $" + formatter.format(Total) + " ");
                    System.out.println(Subtotal);       //testing
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }

                public double getSubtotal()
                {
                    return Subtotal;
                }
```

### }

Comment: you can see i have several attempts to try and force the CheckoutPanel to update, including the adding of setText in Subtotal and then even the removal of the JLabels

Comment: It would be helpful for us (who have never seen your code before) if you could include just enough so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: OK, I have updated the code to the exact way i would like it to run. If you run the code like this, everything works like i want it to but it still does not update the CheckoutPanel with the correct amounts.

Comment: Thank you for updating. You are doing a fine job, and are headed in the right direction. Now, before having others dig into your code, there are still a few steps you should take that will ensure you are getting the best advice. I would encourage you to see the following article: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)